# Rotating hoop with fixed body inside of same mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotation

Please help me to solve this problem. I am unable to understand which force will cause the hoop to bounce.

> A small body $A$ is fixed to the inside of a thin rigid hoop of radius $R$ and mass equal to that of the body $A$. The hoop rolls without slipping over a horizontal plane; at the moments when the body $A$ gets into the lower position, the center of the hoop moves with velocity $v_0$. At what values of $v_0$ will the hoop move without bouncing?

[image]

Comment: How about $v_0 = 0$ ?  :-) . I suspect the intent of the problem is to determine at what starting velocity the body `A` is accelerated vertically with enough momentum to "pull" the hoop off the ground.  That makes this a problem of angular momentum vs. linear velocity.  I'm upvoting 'cause this is a cool problem; but you really ought to show what forces, equations, etc. you've come up with on your own.

Answer (score 1):

All i can think of is this diagram when the mass is at angle theta with vertical.
[image]

I created below equation

$$mgcos(\theta)-N=\frac{mv^2}{R}$$

The velocity of hoop and the body A will reduce as the body A is getting potential energy.

My doubt is what force will cause the hoop to bounce. And the answer v<sub>0</sub>=0 is wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're technically right, since the question asked "**move** without bouncing."  I just hoped it would be a hint that there's some range $0<V<V_{max}$ for which the hoop won't go airborne.   Now, not only does "A" get potential energy, but remember it started with zero kinetic energy.  It's speeding up in the external ref. frame.  Calculate that.